# Seagate Basic USB HDD - error showing an empty directory

Tags: usb, hard-drive

1. I purchased a Seagate Basic 1TB USB HDD.
2. I connected the USB-drive into my Dell-desktop-PC running UBUNTU 22.04. It mounts/unmounts and otherwise behaves normally.
3. I used FreeFileSync to back up ~250GB from my desktop-PC to a directory ("vanmetter") that I created on the USB-drive.
4. On the desktop-PC the USB-drive mounts and unmounts normally; and all directories and files appear and are accessible as expected using "Files 42.6".
5. When the USB-drive is connected to my Dell-laptop-PC (also running UBUNTU 22.04) it mounts and unmounts normally; all expected directories (including "vanmetter") appear in "Files 42.6"; BUT the "vanmetter" directory is EMPTY (i.e. is contains no files).

This behavior is repeatable; that is the USB-drive can be mounted on each of the two UBUNTU-22.04 computers with the same observed results (i.e files appear in the vanmetter directory when the USB-drive is mounted on the desktop-PC and do not appear on the laptop-PC.

Any helpful thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Running the UBUNTU utility "Disks" shows (on both PCs) that ~250GB of the 1TB are being used. However, other differences appear for example filesystem type is blank on the desktop-PC and shown as fuse on the laptop-PC.

Comment: Which filesystem? Do you have permissions on the directory? Try `chmod a+rX /path/to/mount`